# How are bv_len and bi_size each used in struct bio of the linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, struct, io, linux-kernel

This is a question about the Linux kernel, which uses the bio struct to manage input and output operations.

The field bi_size is a property of the struct bio, while bv_len is a field of bio_vec. Which one is used to indicate the length of the read or write, and why are both fields necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A somewhat dated article on this topic can be found at https://lwn.net/Articles/26404/. `bi_size` is the total size of the operation and the bio_vec structures are used to track individual buffers.  The article provides the details you need to use these structures, included the recommended accessors.

Comment: Thank you. After reading some more code, it seems that the sum total of all the individual bv_len fields will be equal to bi_size.